# NSView as a modal sheet

Tags: modal-dialog, nsview

I am able to create a model sheet for an NSWindow and I used the following connection code.

```
[NSApp beginSheet:self.view modalForWindow:[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
```

I unable to create a modal for an NSView, Is it possible to create a modal sheet for NSView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible but you have to embed it in newly created window.
e.g.

```
  NSView *view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 300, 300)];
  self.windowSheet = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:[view frame] styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
  self.windowSheet.contentView = view;
  [NSApp beginSheet:self.windowSheet modalForWindow:[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
```

As you can see in documentation the acceptable argument for beginSheet is only window or its subclasses (e.g. NSPanel)

```
- (void)beginSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet modalForWindow:(NSWindow *)docWindow modalDelegate:(nullable id)modalDelegate didEndSelector:(nullable SEL)didEndSelector contextInfo:(null_unspecified void *)contextInfo NS_DEPRECATED_MAC(10_0, 10_10, "Use -[NSWindow beginSheet:completionHandler:] instead");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I do not want to embed my NSView inside a window, is it possible to do it without embedding into an NSWindow.

Comment: No. The only acceptable argument is NSWindow and it's subclasses. For this reason I did include in my answer the method. Only NSPopover creates window just with view specified. But you want a modal sheet. However you can subclass and play with popover to achieve modal behaviour.

Comment: You have to set the self.windowSheet.ContentView with the view you want to display as sheet.